# how to do i get trunc day date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, date

i want to get the trunc date with such format :

> 20190326

this code in my schema :

```js
 dateCreated: {
     
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
```

gives the following result :

> 2019-03-26T01:05:43.778Z

Answer (score 0):

Use [Aggregation $dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    date: {
      $dateToString: {
        format: "%d%m%Y",
        date: "$dateCreated"
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

You can set formate according to requirement. 
Sample data [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EpJFMgCVNf8).

Comment: thanks for your answer but i wanted to that within my schema. I solved it in a simpler way check my answer below

Comment: In your solution, you set the default value as string format(YYYYMMDD). And it is not a good way in mongoose On saving.

Comment: do you have a better way so it can be done within my schema ?

Answer (score 0):

this solved it :

```js
const date = new Date();
const today = date.getUTCFullYear().toString()+ (date.getUTCMonth()+1)+date.getUTCDate().toString();


export const taskSchema = new Schema ({
dateCreated: {
     
        type: String,
        default: today
    }
});
```